# How to make curl use proxy automatically

Tags: proxy

Today I configured the PC of my company to setup a proxy and it worked because I can `wget` web page via proxy.

What I did is set `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` and `ftp_proxy` in the `~/.bashrc` and in the `~/.wgetrc`.

However, when I tried to `curl www.google.fr`, it blocked and timeout.

`curl --proxy $http_proxy www.google.fr` worked as expected.

Is it possible to make `curl` use the proxy automatically?

Comment: Set the proxy address in `~/.curlrc` as follows: `proxy = <proxy_host>:<proxy_port>`. Let me know if this works out and I will make it into a 'formal' answer...

Comment: @andrew.46  Great, it works. :)

Comment: What exactly did you put in `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @muru   `export http_proxy="http://account:passwd@proxy.xxx.com:8080"   export https_proxy=$http_proxy`

Comment: @muru  ...... Ooooo..... I made a mistake: I forgot the key word `export`...

Comment: @andrew.46  @muru     such a stupid question... @andrew.46 please make an answer, at least, I didn't know to use `.curlrc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to get curl to use a proxy is to add the details into `~/.curlrc` file. The syntax is as follows:

```
proxy = <proxy_host>:<proxy_port>
```

This can *alternatively* be set as an environmental variable but IMHO using `~/.curlrc` is the most direct and least error prone method.

Answer (score 0):

Some proxies require specific authentication headers to be set, so be aware of those as well. In my case, it's `--proxy-ntlm` in the example below:

curl -x webproxy.net:8080 -U usernaname:password http://google.com --proxy-ntlm

Bu there are other options:

`--proxy-digest` and `--proxy-negotiate`

Lastly, cURL has a super friendly [doc page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/), so be sure to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The client `curl` (naturally) uses the library `libcurl` under the hood.

In the context of proxies the [libcurl api documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html) among other things states:

> **Environment variables**
>
> libcurl respects the proxy environment variables named http_proxy,
> ftp_proxy, sftp_proxy etc. If set, libcurl will use the specified
> proxy for that URL scheme. So for a "FTP://" URL, the ftp_proxy is
> considered. all_proxy is used if no protocol specific proxy was set.
>
> If no_proxy (or NO_PROXY) is set, it is the exact equivalent of
> setting the CURLOPT_NOPROXY option.
>
> The CURLOPT_PROXY and CURLOPT_NOPROXY options override environment
> variables.

So if you set the environment variable accordingly, `libcurl` and consequently `curl` will pick it up. Any explicitly set proxy (e.g. in `.curlrc` or via `--proxy` cmdline argument) overwrites the environment variable settings.